# Why onmeasure have to be call in order to display textview in side a linear layout

Tags: java, android

I am creating a custom viewgroup and I added a linear layout with a text view into the linear layout. However, the textview only shows when I define onmeasure method inside my viewgroup. Why is this the case?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class noteLayout extends ViewGroup {
        float leftOrientationSize = 0;
        float rightOrientationSize=0;
        public noteLayout(Context activityContext)
        {
            super(activityContext);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            int numberOfChild = getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0;i<numberOfChild;i++){
                View childView = getChildAt(i);
                float childHeight = (float) childView.getMeasuredHeight();
                float childWidth = (float) childView.getMeasuredWidth();
                RectF rect = new RectF();
                rect.bottom = 300;
                rect.top = 20;
                rect.left = 50;
                rect.right = (getWidth()/2)-20;
                childView.layout((int) rect.left, (int) rect.top, (int) rect.right, (int) rect.bottom);
            }
        }
    }


       private void layoutNoteView() {
            noteLayout noteLayout = new noteLayout(this);
            noteLayout.addView((View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test3,null));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams noteLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            noteLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                noteLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
            }
            noteLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.StartRelativeLayout);
            relativeLayoutMain.addView(noteLayout,noteLayoutParams);
        }
```

btw test3 in the code is an xml layout resource with a linearlayout and a textview and the linear layout has a cyan background. Here is what happens without onMeasure():

[image]

sorry for bad handwriting I tried.

Comment: Show some code and screenshot to demonstrate exactly is not working and how it is different than the way you expect it to work.

Comment: just posted the code and the picture

Comment: If you need  anything  else just tell me I ll post it for you.

Comment: I don't see anything about a TextView in your code. I also don't see where layoutNoteView is ever called.  I also wonder why you're doing things with RelativeLayout parameters when there's no RelativeLayout that can be seen here.

Comment: The text view is part of a linear layout that is define in xml. I just didn't put the xml file because i fon't want to overwhelm you with code. All i did was right click the layout folder and create a layout resource that has a linear layout and within it a linear layout

Comment: Also, the relativelayout is the outside parents of all the view above. As for the layoutnoteview it is definitely call by the root parent relativelayoutmain.addview(notelayout)